# The /boot partition in my server is full, how can I re-size it without re-installing the whole system?

Tags: boot, server, partitioning

I'm having some troubles because the partition in which `/boot` is allocated in my server is full, so I can install neither new linux images nor upgrades.

Here is the server's file system usage information:

```
$  df -Th
Filesystem           Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/PCM-root ext4      442G   83G  337G  20% /
udev                 devtmpfs  7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                tmpfs     3.2G  320K  3.2G   1% /run
none                 tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                 tmpfs     7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1            ext2      228M  225M     0 100% /boot
```

The specific question is how I can manage to solve this issue without re-installing the system (that is what I'm gonna do if everything else fails)?

Comment: You can delete few old kernel images

Comment: From the command-line, you can see which kernels are installed using `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`.  Any with `ii` in the left column are currently installed.  Do note that at least one of those entries is going to be a meta-package (such as `linux-image` or `linux-image-server`)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to unmount the partition, shrink the filesystem with `resize2fs`, and then use either `fdisk` or `parted` to delete and recreate the partition with a smaller size.  Make sure you use units of sectors when partitioning.  You put `fdisk` into sector mode with the `u` command, and parted with the `unit s` command.  Make sure to recreate the partition with the same starting sector, and enough length to cover the size you shrank the filesystem to with `resize2fs`.  Round up to avoid making it too small.